# Replacing JSON pattern

Tags: python, r, replace, pattern-matching

My JSON file is like:

```
{"A":[
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:39:54", "File": "E.kmp", "C":{....},
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:40:32", "File": "E.kmp", "L":{....},
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:41:32", "File": "E.kmp", "L":{....},
................................................................,
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:42:32", "File": "D.kmp", "L":{....},
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:43:32", "File": "D.kmp", "L":{....}
]
```

I want to change all the "File" name as "E.kmp". That's why I need to replace "D.kmp" with "E.kmp".If it is possible with python or R, please help me out. Python is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a for loop to iterate over the dictionaries and replace the value.

```
json_val = {"A":[{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:39:54", "File": "E.kmp"},
                 {"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:49:54", "File": "D.kmp"},
                 {"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:59:54", "File": "D.kmp"}
                ]}
for dic in json_val['A']:
    if dic['File'] != 'E.kmp':
        dic['File'] = 'E.kmp'
print json_val
```

The above snippet replaces the value of the key `File` in all the dictionaries inside the list if the value is not `E.kmp`.

You need not do `json.loads(json_val)` as python can handle json.

Output will be as:

```
{'A': [{'Timestamp': '2017-11-14 14:39:54', 'File': 'E.kmp'}, 
       {'Timestamp': '2017-11-14 14:49:54', 'File': 'E.kmp'}, 
       {'Timestamp': '2017-11-14 14:49:54', 'File': 'E.kmp'}
      ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way in `R`

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
res <- fromJSON(json_val) %>%
             map(mutate, File = 'E.kmp') %>%
             toJSON

prettify(res, indent=1)
# {
# "A": [
#  {
#   "Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:39:54",
#   "File": "E.kmp"
#  },
#  {
#   "Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:49:54",
#   "File": "E.kmp"
#  },
#  {
#   "Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:59:54",
#   "File": "E.kmp"
#  }
# ]
#}
```

#### data

```
json_val <- '{"A":[{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:39:54", "File": "E.kmp"},
             {"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:49:54", "File": "D.kmp"},
             {"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:59:54", "File": "D.kmp"}
            ]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `D.kmp` with `E.kmp`

```
import json    
text = '''
{"A":[
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:39:54", "File": "E.kmp", "C":{....},
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:40:32", "File": "E.kmp", "L":{....},
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:41:32", "File": "E.kmp", "L":{....},
................................................................,
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:42:32", "File": "D.kmp", "L":{....},
{"Timestamp": "2017-11-14 14:43:32", "File": "D.kmp", "L":{....}
]
'''

json_data = json.loads(text)
for element in json_data["A"]:
      if element["File"] == "D.kmp":
          element["File"] = "E.kmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see your entire JSON structure, here is how to do it with replace()

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as file :
    data = file.read()

data = data.replace('"File": "D.kmp"', '"File": "E.kmp"')

with open('file.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are simple way:

```
your_json['A'] =[i for i in your_json['A'] if not i.update({"File":"D.kmp"})]
```